# Oracle SQL: Counting how often an attribute occurs for a given entry and choosing the attribute with the maximum number of occurs

Tags: sql, oracle, count, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a table that has a number column and an attribute column like this:

```
1.
+-----+-----+
| num | att |
-------------
|  1  |  a  | 
|  1  |  b  |
|  1  |  a  |
|  2  |  a  |
|  2  |  b  |
|  2  |  b  |
+------------
```

I want to make the number unique, and the attribute to be whichever attribute occured most often for that number, like this (This is the end-product im interrested in) :

```
2.
+-----+-----+
| num | att |
-------------
|  1  |  a  | 
|  2  |  b  |
+------------
```

I have been working on this for a while and managed to write myself a query that looks up how many times an attribute occurs for a given number like this:

```
3.
+-----+-----+-----+
| num | att |count|
------------------+
|  1  |  a  |  1  |
|  1  |  b  |  2  |
|  2  |  a  |  1  |
|  2  |  b  |  2  |
+-----------------+
```

But I can't think of a way to only select those rows from the above table where the count is the highest (for each number of course).

So basically what I am asking is given table 3, how do I select only the rows with the highest count for each number (Of course an answer describing providing a way to get from table 1 to table 2 directly also works as an answer :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use aggregation and window functions:

```
select num, att
from (
    select num, att, row_number() over(partition by num order by count(*) desc, att) rn
    from mytable
    group by num, att
) t
where rn = 1
```

For each `num`, this brings the most frequent `att`; if there are ties, the smaller `att` is retained.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has an aggregation function that does this, [`stats_mode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions188.htm#SQLRF06320).:

```
select num, stats_mode(att)
from t
group by num;
```

In statistics, the most common value is called the *mode* -- hence the name of the function.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9217d702a2996d4c6b21e51b4770ca48) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by and count as below

```
select id, col, count(col) as count
from
df_b_sql
group by id, col
```